# Kendo UI Grid - remove rows taking long time

Tags: performance, kendo-grid

I am developing a kendo grid in my HTML page and it gets about 500+ records from the backend service.
I created a checkbox for each row, when I select the checkbox, it selects the row.
When I delete the row using below code, it takes about 8 seconds for each record delete.

```
var _gridData = grid.dataSource.data();
        var len = _gridData.length;
        while (len--) {
            if (_gridData[len].check_row == true) { // row has the checkbox ticked
                grid.dataSource.remove(_gridData[len]);
            }
        }
```

Can you let me know why it is taking more time to delete when we have more records say (400+) and takes less time when we have less records say 10-20?

Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a logic problem , i would not loop through the whole data list to find the checked check boxes . i would find all the check box in the gird with checked  using jquery (really fast than looping all the data) and then get the data item and remove it from the dataSource.

```
$("#grid").find('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(index,elem){
var tr=$(elem).closest("tr");
var grid=$("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
var dataItem = grid.dataItem(tr);
grid.dataSource.remove(dataItem );
});
```

**Note : This Code this Not tested might have syntax issues ..**

for the dataitem to work well it is necessary to define a model in your dataSource

Comment: Thanks.. I tried using $.each of grid selected rows like below. But still its taking 8 seconds for each record to remove from the dataSource. `$("#grid tr.k-state-selected").each(function (e) {//remove the row}`

Comment: you may need to enable batch processing to true , so it will send all the request at once . its "batch:true" http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-batch